Cox-like model: weighted sum of proportional hazards
We are trying to do inference on vaccine effectiveness (VE) during an epidemic in a risk-stratified population.
Models:
Consider the Cox model:
$$ \lambda_{ik}(t) = \lambda_0(t) \exp [\beta X_{ik}] $$
and compare with the classic transmission model incidence equation:
$$ \lambda_{ik}(t) = \rho V_k C_i \sum_j \phi_{ij} P_j$$
where:

$i$ denotes self risk group of self, and $j$ denotes contact risk group
$k$ denotes vaccination status
$\rho$ is the base probability of transmission per contact
$V_k$ is the vaccine effect (VE < 1 if vaccinated, else 1)
$C_i$ is the contact rate for risk group $i$
$\phi_{ij}$ is the probability of $i$ individuals forming a given contact with $j$
$P_j = I_j / N_j$ is the prevalence of infection in group $j$.

Case 1: Random Mixing.
Under random mixing, $\phi_{ij}$ does not depend on $i$, so:

$\lambda_0(t) = \rho \sum_j \phi_{*j} P_j(t)$
$\exp[\beta_V X^V_k] = V_k$
$\exp[\beta_C X^C_i] = C_i$

and we have direct correspondence between the Cox and transmission models equations: great!
Case 2: Non-Random Mixing.
If $\phi_{ij}$ depends on $i$, then each group $i$ will experience a unique hazard "$\lambda_{0,i}(t)$", namely an average of prevalence across their contacts' risk groups $j$, weighted by the mixing distribution $\phi_{i*}$:

$\lambda_{0,i}(t) = \rho \sum_j \phi_{ij} P_j(t)$

This evidently violates the proportional hazards assumption between groups / strata $i$. However, it feels like we should still be able to use some trick to infer $\beta_V$ in a Cox-like way - i.e. avoid estimating $P_j(t)$, $\phi_{ij}$, and/or $C_i$ using some kind of conditional likelihood.
If it helps, there are some natural constraints: $0 \le P_j(t) \le 1$, and $0 \le \phi_{ij} \le 1$, and $\sum_j \phi_{ij} = 1$. There are also reasonable parametric forms for $\phi_{ij}$ which we could use to jointly estimate $\phi_{ij}$.
Bonus. Of course, $P_j(t)$ is actually an output from the transmission model, so any insights about if / how estimates could be constrained via feedback from $\lambda_i(t)$ would be stellar.
